# How to communicate between internal Git repo behind firewall with external machine?

Tags: git, firewall

Here's my situation: I have an upstream repo which is behind a corporate firewall. But the development machine is outside the firewall. How can I communicate between them? I am able to access InternalPC files from ExternalPC via Remote Desktop \\tsclient

```
UpstreamRepo <--> InternalPC <--|firewall|--> ExternalPC
```

Currently, what I do is use InternalPC to do all the git commands (fetch, merge, commit, push, etc). Then I manually copy the files back and forth between InternalPC and ExternalPC. But that doesn't allow me to do branches and commits on ExternalPC because they would be overwritten when I copy files from InternalPC to ExternalPC.

Is there a better way to do this? One idea I had was if I could do a `git fetch <InternalPC>` and `git push <InternalPC>` from ExternalPC. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erik's idea was right on. Amazing how Git works. Here's exactly what I did:

ExternalPC:

```
git remote set-url origin //tsclient/C/Users/yourname/git
git pull
```

InternalPC: (Cannot have master branch checked out when pushing to it, so you checkout any other branch)

```
git checkout <some-branch-not-master>
```

ExternalPC:

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

You can of course use git pull from external PC on Internal PC, e.g. via SSH. Or you can use the Upstream Repo to push to. Or you can open a port in the firewall to access internal PC. Which ports are open, btw?

Comment: So you mean from InternalPC, I can do `git pull <ExternalPC>`? Even though ExternalPC is a "local repo" rather than an "upstream repo"?  

Only ssh and http/s ports are open. @Erik

Comment: Yes, that was the idea. It doesn't matter if you pull or push between repos. git is distributed, and there is no "canonical" repository. If ssh to the internal is open through the firewall, you can use ssh to access the repo on internal from external as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your scenario is:

1. You work for government so any change is hard
2. Windows RDP from LOCAL to REMOTE with drives shared
3. All coding is done on REMOTE
4. You are scared REMOTE will die, and you want to backup to a shared drive that is only available to LOCAL.

Initial Steps:

1. Check the mapped LOCAL drive name. For it was `H:\`
2. Create base folder for your code, for me it is `H:\Code`
3. Open git bash
4. `cd //tsclient/H/Code`
5. `git clone --no-checkout --local file://C:/Projects/MyImportantProject`
6. You have have your repository cloned into LOCAL `H:\Code\MyImportantProject`
7. `cd //tsclient/H/Code/MyImportantProject`
8. `git remote add remotebox file://C:/Projects/MyImportantProject`

Backup Step:

1. Do you work on LOCAL and commit
2. Open git bash
3. `cd //tsclient/H/Code/MyImportantProject`
4. `git pull remotebox master`